# What is Silverlight, and to what types of developers would it be beneficial to know and learn?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Is Silverlight just basically Microsoft's version of Adobe Flash?  If so, I've read over the years that Flash is very SEO unfriendly (SE bots see it as a blank page, I've been told), and some browsers don't like Flash too much.  Are the same things true for Silverlight?

I just have a company website I made in Visual Studio 2010 / vb / asp.net 4.0.

Do you have to be an experienced programmer to work with Silverlight, or is there a nice GUI to help out newbies?  I'm just trying to find out, now that I've downloaded 5.0, if the value of learning it is worth it.  Thanks!

Comment: Too many question in one topic. Not very SEO friendly for people looking for similar answers...

Comment: Silverlight is essentially dead: HTML5 + CSS3

Comment: The question is about Silverlight as a platform. That Silverlight simply isn't SEO friendly doesn't mean it can be tuned to support search engines. In essence Silverlight is obviously not all about SEO.

Comment: @MitchWheat no it's not. Windows Phone 7 + Xbox360.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silverlight is a lot of things, in summary you could say that it's a light-weight .NET run-time, a subset of WPF and a capable video player.

Silverlight brings XAML to the web, yes, but more importantly it appears that it's becoming more and more a framework for deploying rich business applications over the web, but not through the browser.

Some would probably argue that Silverlight (along with Flash) is dead, and that the HTML5 is the way forward. That might be true, under certain circumstances but Silverlight has a lot of cool data binding tricks as well as a very capable retained mode render which is very suitable for business GUIs.

I would argue that the choice wheter to invest in Silverlight as a technology or not is a question you should ask yourself, basically what's your reach? e.g. I would not develop Facebook using Silverlight because Facebook has to be everywhere. If you wanna go social, then the web is ubiquitous. But if you have a customer base that acknowledge Microsoft, and already run Windows everywhere, the kind of headway you can make with Silverlight is quite astonishing.

I urge you to look at some Silverlight demos to gain a better feel for what Silverlight has to offer. Then to build great Silverlight applications you need to invest time in learning, things like XAML and MVVM (using a lot of data binding).

Comment: Hey John, thanks your your time in responding.  I appreciate that!  I've been to forums.silverlight.net, and other things I've googled, but they're mostly written in techy terms that I'm not intelligent enough to comprehend.  But thank you for summing up what it's about, in Layman's terms, per se, and for providing some insight into Silverlight!

Comment: 'retrain mode render' ?? I don't get you. Are you talking about 'retained mode'? Else, +1 good points.

Comment: @jv42 Ah, yes, that's a typo. It's supposed to read **retained** mode

Answer (score 3):

Silver light is Microsoft's option or alternative to adobe flash its provides user with the feature of developing Application that are rich in UI we do have tools that enable us to develop appealing UI that is Expression Blend. SO there is lot to learn in it but talking about the future of this technology i doubt as after HTML 5.0 which enables us to get most of the features of silver-light i don't think any one will be interested to get an add on plugin to silver-light to achieve same result so its up to u if u want to learn it as some new technology its good but as a future its not that great.

Comment: You're the 3rd person just in this thread that mentioned html5 + css3, both of which I'm familiar with.  Thank you for taking the time to respond, Karan, and offering your opinion.  I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1):

SEO friendliness depends on the amount of effort your developers are ready to put into it, Silverlight and Flash both. Silverlight has a framework (Navigation) allowing deep linking that can help for instance.

The tool chain is top class, you get the arguably best IDE (Visual Studio 2010), and a cool designer friendly tool (Blend) that enables, among other things, non-code oriented development, or put the other way, a designer friendly workflow. The XAML+data binding approach is also much more productive than most of the competing alternative (personal opinion, but shared by many developers).

The value of using and of learning Silverlight both is very dependent on your company's objective and skill set. If you already have proficient .NET developers, intend to target Windows Phone or Windows 8 or even do some WPF (Windows desktop counterpart of Silverlight), the learning is either small or a good one. If you're a pure web shop, valuing multiplatform, needing iOS/Android/etc... support, you're probably better off with HTML+CSS+JS.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, jv42 -- I appreciate your insight!  I think I'm going to delve a little bit more into Silverlight, and get a rudimentary understanding of it, while keeping a watchful eye on html5 and css3.  Thank you again for your time!